# FileNotFound error when loading assets in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am learning how to use Pygame and when I am loading the assets to use in my project it gives me a FileNotFound error. The code it gives me an error at is `NORMAL_BINGUS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', 'Bingus_Normal.jpg'))`

The assets folder is in the same folder my code is in, and the image name is exactly the same as I typed above, so I do not know what the cause for this could be.

Comment: code may run in different folder and it may search assets in wrong folder - you may need `os.path.join(BASE, 'assets','Bingus_Normal.jpg')` where `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: alr, ill try that

Comment: didnt work, anything else?

Comment: correction: it has to be `dirname()` instead of `basename()`

Comment: oh alr ill change it

Comment: nice it works now, ill mark the question as answered

Comment: this problem was so many times on Stackoverflow so I would rather find some other question and close your question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code may run in a different folder and it may search assets in the wrong place.

You need to create an absolute path to the folder with the code.

```
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

And later use it to create an absolute path to every asset:

```
os.path.join(BASE, 'assets', 'Bingus_Normal.jpg')
```